# Can't install updates, Pleas help

Tags: updates

Hi I cannot install updates either from the terminal or from the system settings. And also having trouble installing software too at times.

It's saying things like failed to fetch stuff and `E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

If any of you could help me with this I'll be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Certainly - could you post the exact output it says? That will help in understanding the exact problem.

Comment: That was quick, thanks. I have pasted what all the errors from the terminal on pasebin if that's any help to you at all: http://pastebin.com/wUjshaZL If you want I can post it here too as well.

Comment: Is your computer sitting behind a proxy server? Seems like you have an issue with the proxy.

Comment: It was but but I removed the proxy server as I thought it that might be the problem. However still having problems. I installed Dansguardian before. I now don't think I needed to remove it; probably just disable while updating. But I don't know how to change this or even remember how I set up Dansguardian in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

To change your system wide proxy settings, click on system settings and select Network. In the next screen, make it look as follows:
[image]

Then click apply system wide.

It should have removed the proxy from intercepting your internet traffic.